# Formato moneda PHP

Tags: php

estoy realizando un listado de registros en PHP, y me encuentro con que un campo de tipo double no puedo darle formato de moneda, he investigado y escribo el código correspondiente, pero no cambia, solo lo hace cuando uso el formato en_US

aquí el código

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'es_MX');
                    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                      echo '<tr>
                            <td>'.$row['ticket'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['fecha'].'</td>
                            <td>'.money_format('%i',$row['total']).'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['vendedor'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row['formadepago'].'</td>
                            </tr>';
                    }
```

los números salen sin separador de miles ni el signo de moneda, aunque bueno, sería suficiente con el separador de miles.

de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes utilizar `number_format` en su lugar.

Comment: la respuesta de PhpMyguel es aceptable, pero no me funcionó, probé con este comando y logré hacer lo que deseaba, muchas gracias jonathan Orta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo revisaría lo que estás tratando de convertir a formato moneda (`$row['total']`) porque con un `double` no debería estar dándote problema. Por otro lado, si lo que quieres es mostrar el símbolo monetario local, no lo estás haciendo correctamente.

**PHP**

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'es_MX');

$numero = (double) 1332.52;
$string = '1332.52';


echo money_format('%n', $numero); //Muestra: $ 1,332.52
echo '<br>';
echo money_format('%n', $string); //Muestra: $ 1,332.52
echo '<br>';
echo money_format('%i', $numero); //Lo que tú tienes muestra: MXN 1,332.52
```

Como ves la conversión a moneda sucede tanto si el valor es un `double` como si es un `string`.

Comment: Hola, es que ni si quiera esto muestra
`echo money_format('%i', $numero); //Lo que tú tienes muestra: MXN 1,332.52` y el campo es de tipo double, solo se lista el número separado con los decimales.